# How to name docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How do you name your `docker-compose.yml` files? Is there a convention to follow?

With Dockerfiles `<purpose>.Dockerfile` seems to work the best being instantly recognized by VSCode and PyCharm.

I like the idea of structuring docker/compose files into folders so that default names could be used, but as far as I know docker can't see files up the tree creating different problems.

Comment: I name them exactly `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`, and generally store them in the top-level directory of the repository that uses them.  Do you have a specific use case where they need to have non-default names?

Comment: @DavidMaze one use case for non-default names is having multiple compose files - one for production and one for development.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [`-f` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files):

> If you don’t provide this flag on the command line, Compose [...] looks for a
>   `docker-compose.yml` and a `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

If you don't want to use the `-f` flag you can use the **default** name `docker-compose.yml` and **override** it with `docker-compose.override.yml`.

---

However, if you use `-f`, since you'll provide the filename, you can use **whatever** you want.

I think a good way to name them depending on the **environment** could be `docker-compose.{env}.yml` and place them at the top level directory:

- `docker-compose.prod.yml`
- `docker-compose.dev.yml`
- `docker-compose.test.yml`
- `docker-compose.staging.yml`

And you can use the default `docker-compose.yml` to define the **base configuration** that is **common** to all environments.